# Instruments Energy Diagnostics -> Battery as percentage

Tags: ios, instruments

I ran several long-term battery tests using Developer >> Logging for Energy Diagnostics.  I've sent them all into instruments where I am able to determine the "Energy Usage Level".  However, is it possible to also get the battery percentage at that moment instead of the "Energy Usage Level".

I was hoping to be able to graph the battery life percentage over time during the application running, along with determining when my application woke from sleep or turned on GPS.

The testing was done on an iPhone 4, iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: Does that also work on ipod 4th generation , i run it on iphone 4S also and it always shows energy usage as 0/20 ?
Any idea why so , which devices and os version is supported by this tool ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Powergremlin](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/11/14/introducing-powergremlin/) doesn't do exactly what you're looking for, but it is [open source](https://github.com/palominolabs/powergremlin) so might start you on the way to implementing it yourself.

Comment: Interesting.  Any clue if you can save it the results to the csv instead of manually checking it?

Comment: @Falcon165o: now that I see those words written I realize that's a great feature. File a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/palominolabs/powergremlin/issues) to make sure I don't forget to implement that.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it is not possible.  I ended up writing an application that would write to a database the percentage of the battery after a x time wait.  It's a shame that apples own tool does not work that way :\